# How to divide page with iframe

Tags: jquery, html, css, jsp, twitter-bootstrap

If you look at the images, how can I "divide" page with `iframe`like that ?

[image: divide]

thank you

Comment: Just wondering, why would this need `iframe`?

Comment: `iframe.open('url')`, where `iframe` is iframe's window handler

Comment: Example of not using `iframe` for this. [**DEMO HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/Ruddy/SW7nj/) Little more updated [**DEMO HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/Ruddy/SW7nj/1/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<FRAMESET ROWS="30%,70%">
    <FRAME SRC="Noname1.html" NAME="frm1" ID="frm1">
    <FRAMESET COLS="25%,75%">
        <FRAME SRC="Noname1.html" NAME="frm2" ID="frm2">
        <FRAME SRC="Noname1.html" NAME="frm3" ID="frm3">
    </FRAMESET>
</FRAMESET>
</html>
```

Noname1.html

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        $('#test').click(function(){
            alert('clicked');
        });
        $(window.parent.frm3.document).find('#test').click();
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Frameset is now deprecated https://www.w3.org/TR/html5-diff/#obsolete-elements. `iFrame`s are now the solution to date.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a `JSFiddle` for what you asked: http://jsfiddle.net/4AvmM/

However, there are better ways to do it as [Ruddy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2259322/ruddy) commented:

> a link [DEMO HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/Ruddy/SW7nj/) Little more updated [DEMO HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/Ruddy/SW7nj/1/)